# Avoiding warning "boxing immediately unboxed to perform coercion"

Tags: java, findbugs

I want to typecast from double to long without having

**BX_BOXING_IMMEDIATELY_UNBOXED_TO_PERFORM_COERCION bug.**

I am stuck in this statement which gives the above **bug**.

Please  help me out

```
long orderedQty = new Double(placedQty).longValue();
```

Comment: This question needs properly tagging, otherwise we're all guessing which language you're using.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `placedQty` is a primitive `double`, you could cast directly:

```
long orderedQty = (long) placedQty;
```

If `placedQty` was a `String` (which I don't think is the case here), you could say

```
long orderedQty = Long.parseLong(placedQty);
```

The rationale behind the FindBugs warning is that you are creating an Object only to help convert a value, which is unnecessary.